# Why can't i pass Dictionary<string, string> to IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> as generic type

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, delegates, ienumerable

I would like some explanation. I have a generic class that get a list of type T and execute a Delegate method on it but I want to pass a IEnumerable to my class to be able to treat List, Dictionary, etc.

Assuming this code :

```
        public static class GenericClass<T>
        {
            public delegate void ProcessDelegate(ref IEnumerable<T> p_entitiesList);

            public static void ExecuteProcess(ref IEnumerable<T> p_entitiesList, ProcessDelegate p_delegate)
            {
                p_delegate(ref p_entitiesList);
            }
        }


        public static void Main()
        {
          GenericClass<KeyValuePair<string, string>.ProcessDelegate delegateProcess = 
                new GenericClass<KeyValuePair<string, string>.ProcessDelegate(
                delegate (ref IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> p_entitiesList)
                    {
                        //Treatment...
                    });

          Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>;
          GenericClass<KeyValuePair<string, string>>.ExecuteProcess(ref dic, delegateProcess);
            //I get this error : 
            //  cannot convert from ref Dictionary<string, string> to ref IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        }
```

I would like some explanation about why can't I pass an Dictionnary as a IEnumerable of KeyValuePair because Dictionary inherit from IEnumerable and use KeyValuePair.

Also, is their a better way doing this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it's a `ref` parameter.

A `ref` parameter means that the method can assign a new value to the field / variable passed by the caller.

Had your code been legal, the method would be able to assign a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, which is obviously wrong.

You should not use `ref` parameters.

Comment: It was fast ! Thank you very much that solved my problem. I've been searching for a solution since this morning. I was never expecting the `ref` to be the problem

Comment: Yes, it's the `ref`. Of course the variable passed to a `ref` parameter *must* have the exact same compile-time type as the parameter. The runtime type of the object actually inside the variable passed could be more derived of course, as in `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();`. But if the `ref` is not really needed (in this case) it is much better and easier to get rid of it.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, I don't understand what do you mean by :  "The runtime type of the object actually inside the variable passed could be more derived of course, as in IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();"

Comment: @Tareck117: He means that a variable of (compile-time-)type `IEnumerable<T>` can hold a more-derived type, such as `List<T>` or `Dictionary<>`.  (assuming the type parameters are variantly compatible)

Comment: @Tareck117 Yes, SLaks is right. If you have a method that has a `ref Animal` parameter, the variable you pass for that parameter must be of "compile-time type" `Animal`. Exactly, not more or less derived. When the program runs, the reference may be `null`, or may refer an actual object whose "run-time type" is more derived than `Animal`, say `Giraffe`. Here is an example: `Animal myVar = new Giraffe(); /* compile-time type and run-time type of myVar do not agree */ Method(ref myVar); /* OK, Method got an Animal. After method returns, variable myVar may hold an Elephant */`